# Mapview - protection against coordinates found nil

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mkmapview, fatal-error

I have mapview that downloads records off CloudKit. The coordinates of each record is based on forward geocoder, where users add the address (ex: New York, NY) and lats and lons are obtained

Current Model is as follow:

```
class Place: NSObject
{
  var name: String
  var address: String
  var comment: String?
  var photo: UIImage?
  var rating: Int
  var location: CLLocation?
  var identifier: String
  var record: CKRecord!

  init(record: CKRecord)
  {
    self.record = record
    self.name = record.valueForKey(placeName) as! String
    self.address = record.valueForKey(placeAddress) as! String
    self.comment = record.valueForKey(placeComment) as? String

    if let photoAsset = record.valueForKey(placePhoto) as? CKAsset
    {
      self.photo = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: photoAsset.fileURL)!)
    }

    self.rating = record.valueForKey(placeRating) as! Int
    self.location = record.valueForKey(placeLocation) as? CLLocation

    self.identifier = record.recordID.recordName
  }

  // MARK: Map Annotation

  var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    get {
      return location!.coordinate
    }
  }
```

This is my method to place each pin on the mapview.

```
func placePins()
  {
    for place: Place in self.places
    {

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.coordinate.latitude, place.coordinate.longitude)
        let dropPin = CustomPointAnnotation(place: place)
        dropPin.pinCustomImageName = "customPin"
        dropPin.coordinate = location
        dropPin.title = place.title
        dropPin.subtitle = place.subtitle
        dropPin.name = place.name
        dropPin.image = place.photo
        mapView.addAnnotation(dropPin)

    }
  }
```

How do i fix them to protect against any record that doesn't have coordinates since forward geocoder is not the most reliable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
for place: Place in self.places
    {
        if (place.location == nil) {
            continue;
        }
        ...
    }
```

Not sure what is the issue there